# How to integrate django authentication with react-router?

Tags: django, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to build a website with react frontend and django backend. I used to have my landing page using django template and the after logging in, it will be a react app. But this time round, I would like to try a different approach. I want the entire application to be react frontend only. However, the issue now is how do I authenticate the user as they navigate across the website?

React 0.14

React Router 2.0

Django 1.8.8

Answer (score 1):

try `JWT` with Django+react, see: https://github.com/Seedstars/django-react-redux-jwt-base

Comment: @Mox Hi, one of the developers of that project here. We updated that project and now we use Django Rest Knox instead of JWT. We choose to switch from JWT to Knox because with Knox we can terminate the session in the server side, which was not possible with JWT.